# call another function from onreadystatechange Angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript

How can I call one of my Component function from `onreadystatechange` (because it does not recognize `this` as my class but as `xmlhttpelement`)

```
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4) {
        if (xmlhttp.status == 200) {
          this.anotherFunction(xmlhttp); //this is considered as xmlhttp instead of my class which contains this function
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use arrow function instead:

```
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = () => {
...
}
```

This way `this` will reference to component instance